# How to extract all key frames from a video clip?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract key frames from a video clip. I tried the following command, but it extracts all frames.

```
ffmpeg -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" -i 2.flv -vsync 2 -s 73x41 -r 30 -f image2 thumbnails-%%02d.jpeg
```

Answer (score 35):

You can make this simpler using `-skip_frame` without the need for `select` video filter:

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i 2.flv -vsync 0 -r 30 -f image2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

Comment: Amazing, takes less than 10s on a 20min video compared to more than 3 minutes with select filter !

Comment: Make sure to use `-threads 1`, compared to the default `-threads auto` it makes a `cropdetect` filter graph (`ffmpeg -threads 1 -skip_frame nokey -i input.mkv -filter:v select='not(mod(n\,20))',cropdetect -an -f null /dev/null`) 2x as fast on my system (60s down to 30s)!

Comment: I would not use skip_frame nokey. Have you even checked the output? On my files and build (aug 2019) I get improper time stamps, as in nokey gives me the preceding frame before the I frame, while the nonfiltered/all frames show the I frame at a later time stamp.

Comment: The reason @genpfault suggests using `-threads 1` is that otherwise the sequence of the output keyframes can be issued out-of-order. If you have some kind of *post-hoc* way of dealing with this problem, you can retain multi-threading. Also, it seems that it's still possible to get out-of-order keyframes, ***even when using*** `-threads 1`, but now in this case all such occurrences seem to be accompanied/flagged by an h264 decoder error `illegal short term buffer state detected`.

Comment: Please do add an explanation on why `-vsync 0` is important for this task.

I didn't know what it did and I ended up with a lot of duplicate jpegs because the output matched the framerate of the input, and you need the `-vsync 0` option to avoid that

Comment: What does `-r 30` mean? Should it be equal to video framerate? If I set 30 and it was in fact 60, will I lose 50% of frames? Can't it autodetect?

Answer (score 14):

Example using the [`select`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#aselect_002c-select) and [`scale`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i 2.flv -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I),scale=73x41" \
-vsync vfr -qscale:v 2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

A few tips:

- Filters should not come before the `-i` option, as they're an output option. I don't know where exactly you got the command from, but `PICT_TYPE_I` does not exist –  it should be `I`.
- In the `scale` filter you can replace `73` or `41` to have the filter automatically calculate the width or height to preserve aspect ratio: such as `scale=73:-1` or `scale=-1:41`. This prevents stretching or squishing that can result from "forced" scaling.
- Output quality can be controlled with `-qscale:v` (or the alias `-q:v`). Effective range is a linear scale of 2 to 31 and a lower value is a higher quality.
- That your `ffmpeg` allows a filter before the input tells me it could be outdated. Download [a recent static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for your operating system, or build it yourself according to [the compilation guides](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide) if the above does not work.

Comment: If your goal is to extract the key frames losslessly, you can try the following: `ffmpeg -i 2.flv -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync vfr frame-%02d.png`

Comment: If your goal is to extract the key frames losslessly, you should use lossless avif. That will preserve YCbCr.

Answer (score 0):

If this errors：

> Option vf (set video filters) cannot be applied to input url 1508.mp4 -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
> Error parsing options for input file 1508.mp4.
> Error opening input files: Invalid argument

you can do this：

```
ffmpeg -i 263.mp4 -vf select=eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)  -vsync 2 -s 480x320 -r 24 -f image2 thumbnails-%05d.jpeg
```

“-i” Parameters in advance