# Extracting the index of key frames from a video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg for extracting key frames from a video.
This is the command:

```
ffmpeg -i test2.mp4 -vf select='eq(pict_type\,I)' -vsync 2 -s 160x90 -f image2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg
```

How can I get the index of each key frame extracted in the video? For example, for the first I-frame, the index would be 0, for the second, it would be 24, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/669716/how-to-extract-all-key-frames-from-a-video-clip

Comment: Look into using ffprobe then post process the output to get the index?

Comment: @dstob could you explain more about what you mean ? as I'm new to ffmpeg.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The frame number in the video frames, ex. the first frame of the video would be at index 0

I want to know the index of each key frame in the video frames.

Comment: You want the frame number to be printed on the thumbnail (on the image itself)?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Hm. I hadn't thought of that. Actually I guessed the OP might want to rename the files based on that info.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382656/get-keyframes-of-video-ffmpeg || http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18085458/checking-keyframe-interval

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Like @dstob mentioned, you can use `ffprobe` to get the I-frames and their associated information. `ffprobe` comes with some of the [static builds on the download page](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and can be built from source as well.

This is assuming you're on Linux/Unix:

#### Extract frames and frame types

```bsh
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames \
-show_entries frame=pict_type \
-of csv bbb480.avi \
| grep -n I | cut -d ':' -f 1
```

The `grep` command filters lines with `I` in them, and counts their index (using the `-n` option). The `cut` command selects the first column of the output only (the index). Note that this index is 1-based, not 0-based.

#### Rename output files based on index

You can actually pipe these indices to a list:

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_frames \
-show_entries frame=pict_type \
-of csv bbb480.avi \
| grep -n I | cut -d ':' -f 1 > frame_indices.txt
```

Then make a list of all the thumbnails too:

```
ls -1 thumbnails*.jpeg > thumbnails.txt
```

Then paste those two together:

```
paste thumbnails.txt frame_indices.txt > combined.txt
```

The list now contains the name of the thumbnail and the index. Perform a rename based on that:

```bsh
while read -r thumbnail index; do
  newIndex=$(echo $index - 1 | bc) # subtract 1 from the index
  mv -- "$thumbnail" "thumbnail-$newIndex.jpeg"  # rename file
done < combined.txt
```

The above will rename `thumbnail-01.jpeg` to `thumbnail-0.jpeg`. Note that there is no zero-padding on the output index. If you want to zero-pad it to, say, 5 digits, use `printf`:

```
newIndex=$(printf '%05d' $(echo $index - 1 | bc))
```

On Windows, you'd do the exact same with `ffprobe` but parse the output differently. No idea how to perform the renaming there though.

Comment: This error is displayed:
    'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: That's because you're on Windows. Like I said, this answer assumes Linux or Unix. You were not being more specific in your question. You can achieve the same on Windows using [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) or similar GNU/Linux layers for Windows.

Comment: This is a huge help, thanks. One correction: I think the indices in your first command are off by a factor of three, because there is a `[FRAME]` line and a `[/FRAME]` line for every `pict_type` line.

Comment: @JackO'Connor There is only one line per frame if you use the `-of csv` option for `ffprobe`. What you're describing is the default output format, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use FFMPEG as originally stated, You can list all or partial listing as well as create jpg with the following:

```
ffmpeg.exe \
  -i "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\jpegs and list\VideoName.mp4" \
  -t 15 \
  -vf select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_I)" \
  -vsync 2 \
  -s 160x90 \
  -f image2 thumbnails-%02d.jpeg \
  -loglevel debug 2>&1| for /f "tokens=4,8,9 delims=. " %d in ('findstr "pict_type:I"') do echo %d %e.%f>>"keyframe_list.txt"
```

Remove `-t 15` for no time limit or change to suit.
Remove `-s 160x90 -f image2 thumbnail-%02d.jpeg` or change to suit for thumbnail removal.

Comment: In Windows 7 CMD, this fails at the \. Changing \ to ^ causes a fail at the :I" . Do you have a version that works on Windows?