# Get the list of I-Frames in a video in FFMPEG / Python

Tags: video, ffmpeg, python, video-encoding, iframe

I'm trying to select say 10 frames from a given video, possibly with highest variety and scenes. I would like to experiment with various selection scenarios, but the good thing is that the notion of `I-frame` inherently means scene changes! So I would like to get the I-frames. But maybe there are many I-frames, so probably I have to sample them.

How can I get the list of all I-frames's frame_number in a video in FFMpeg or Python? I would like to use the list to select only 10 of them and save them as PNG/JPEG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting insights from **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798634/extracting-keyframes-python-opencv/51666059#51666059)**, I was able to do it with `ffprobe`:

```
def iframes():
    if not os.path.exists(iframe_path):
        os.mkdir(iframe_path)
    command = 'ffprobe -v error -show_entries frame=pict_type -of default=noprint_wrappers=1'.split()
    out = subprocess.check_output(command + [filename]).decode()
    f_types = out.replace('pict_type=','').split()
    frame_types = zip(range(len(f_types)), f_types)
    i_frames = [x[0] for x in frame_types if x[1]=='I']
    if i_frames:
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename)
        for frame_no in i_frames:
            cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_no)
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            outname = iframe_path+'i_frame_'+str(frame_no)+'.jpg'
            cv2.imwrite(outname, frame)
        cap.release()
        print("I-Frame selection Done!!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    iframes()
```

Comment: Thanks, Tina, for coming back and posting your solution, esp after all these people answered something other than your question.

Answer (score 6):

This seems like an X/Y problem, so I'll propose several different commands:

## List of timestamps

If you want to output a list of timestamps for each keyframe:

```
ffprobe -v error -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 input
0.000000
2.502000
3.795000
6.131000
10.344000
12.554000
```

Note the `-skip_frame nokey`.

## select filter

Another method is to use the [select filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect) with the `scene` option to output your thumbnails:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "select=gt'(scene,0.4)',scale=160:-1" -vsync vfr %04d.png
```

Answer (score 2):

This will output all the i frames as PNG images.

```
ffmpeg -i 2.flv -vf "select=eq(pict_type\,I)" -vsync vfr frame-%02d.png
```

Credit to this comment a similar superuser.com question.
[How to extract all key frames from a video clip?](https://superuser.com/questions/669716/how-to-extract-all-key-frames-from-a-video-clip#comment1184347_669733)

Hope that helps. Cheers.

Ian

Comment: Thanks, but I know this. What I asked is the array of the I-frame indexes in code!

Answer (score 0):

For get frame type of all frames in video you can use the following python function. See original solution [here](https://gist.github.com/alastairmccormack/7041ee993adb5c911f90#file-iframe-probe-py).

```
def get_frames_metadata(file):
    command = '"{ffexec}" -show_frames -print_format json "{filename}"'.format(ffexec='ffprobe', filename=file)
    response_json = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, stderr=None)
    frames = json.loads(response_json)["frames"]
    frames_metadata, frames_type, frames_type_bool = [], [], []
    for frame in frames:
        if frame["media_type"] == "video":
            video_frame = json.dumps(dict(frame), indent=4)
            frames_metadata.append(video_frame)
            frames_type.append(frame["pict_type"])
            if frame["pict_type"] == "I":
                frames_type_bool.append(True)
            else:
                frames_type_bool.append(False)
    print(frames_type)
    return frames_metadata, frames_type, frames_type_bool
```

Output result:

```
['I', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'I', 'P']
```

Where I and P it is frame type.